# Display formatting of Math mode acronyms and glossary items

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

The following MWE using math mode acronyms and glossary items works fine functionally.  But these items are (unsurprisingly) formatted in math mode and this clashes with the text formatting of non-math items.  I suppose formatting the text items as math mode would give a consistent format.  But are there any better options (primarily to give a good-looking display)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, book]{memoir}

\RequirePackage[makeindex,acronym]{glossaries}%

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ecg}{name={EC}, description={Espoir de chelem}}
\newglossaryentry{ec}{type=\acronymtype, name={EC}, description={Espoir de chelem}, first={Espoir de chelem (EC)\glsadd{ecg}}, see=[Glossary:]{ecg}}

\newglossaryentry{sansecg}{name={\ensuremath{\sim{}EC}}, description={Sans espoir de chelem}}
\newglossaryentry{sansec}{type=\acronymtype, name={\ensuremath{\sim{}EC}}, description={Sans espoir de chelem}, first={Sans espoir de chelem (\ensuremath{\sim{}EC})\glsadd{sansecg}}, see=[Glossary:]{sansecg}}

\begin{document} 

First use \gls{ec}\\
Subsequent use \gls{ec}\\
\newpage 
Subsequent use \gls{ec}\\

First use \gls{sansec}\\
Subsequent use \gls{sansec}\\
\newpage 
Subsequent use \gls{sansec}\\


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
Acronyms
∼ EC Sans espoir de chelem. 2, 3, Glossary: ∼ EC
**EC** Espoir de chelem. 1, 2, Glossary: EC

Glossary
∼ EC Sans espoir de chelem. 2
**EC** Espoir de chelem. 1
```

P.S.  In my live file I get the correct headings "Acronymes" and "Glossaire".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work OK

```
\RequirePackage[overload]{textcase}%

\newcommand{\edc}{Espoir de chelem}%  

\newglossaryentry{ecg}{name={EC}, description={\edc}}%
\newglossaryentry{ec}{type=\acronymtype, name={EC}, description={\edc}, first={\edc (EC)\glsadd{ecg}}, see=[Glossary:]{ecg}}%

\newglossaryentry{sansecg}{name={\ensuremath{\sim}EC}, description={Sans \MakeLowercase{\edc}}}%
\newglossaryentry{sansec}{type=\acronymtype, name={\ensuremath{\sim}EC}, description={Sans \MakeLowercase{\edc}}, first={Sans \MakeLowercase{\edc} (\ensuremath{\sim}EC)\glsadd{sansecg}}, see=[Glossary:]{sansecg}}%
```

It didn't look very well when in a list.  I eventually went with

```
\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\mbox{#1}}$}
```

used as follows:

```
\newcommand{\edm}{Espoir~de~manche}%  
\newcommand{\sansedm}{Sans~\MakeLowercase{\edm}}%  

\newglossaryentry{sansecg}{name={\textoverline{EC}},sort={~EC},description={\sansedc}}%

\newglossaryentry{sansec}{type=\acronymtype, sort={~EC}, name={\textoverline{EC}}, description={\sansedc}, first={\sansedc~(\textoverline{EC})\glsadd{sansecg}}}%
```